# getToken google+ login Android GoogleAuthException: Unknown

Tags: android, google-plus

This only happens when I call getToken(param, param, param, param).

I am not certain what I am doing wrong. Here is my code leading up to and including getToken:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_ACTIONS,
                             "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity");
                    bundle.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES, "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity");

                    String clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";

                    if(MyApplication.PRODUCTION){
                        clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    } else {
                        clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    }

                    String scopes = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + clientId + ":api_scope:oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
                    LogUtils.log("scopes string: " + scopes);
                    accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(ctx, mPlusClient.getAccountName(), scopes, bundle);


                  LogUtils.log("access token: " + accessToken);
```

In return I get an Exception:

```
01-31 17:38:28.093: I/test(7124): GoogleAuthException: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out to be the Id being used on someone elses account too.

Works now.